# Could not execute impdp command from docker exec command

Tags: oracle, docker, impdp

I have an oracle 12 docker container where i executed the command "impdp" from docker exec command to import data, but it fails. The error says:

```
UDI-01089: operation generated ORACLE error 1089
ORA-01089: immediate shutdown or close in progress - no operations are permitted
```

Command:

```
docker exec --tty <container_name> /bin/bash -c 'impdp <arguments>'
```

I can see the import was started, but somehow it was interrupted and above error was thrown. Any idea ?

Comment: The error suggests the database is being shut down. But I'd also suspect the environment might not be fully set up in the bash shell that's being created to run `impdp` What do you see if you connect to the same database and user through SQL\*Plus or some other client, directly and through the same `docker exec` mechanism?

Comment: with SQL*Plus and sql developer client i am able to connect successfully. Another interesting point, if i run impdp with a bash script inside a container it works fine. The only issue is when i run impdp with docker exec, then it is giving me this error.

Comment: What about when you run `sqlplus` with `docker exec`? Anyway, it seems like a difference in the environment between the two shells, assuming you are supply the same arguments when you run the command directly inside the container.

Comment: I'm not familiar with docker, but the symptoms you describe sounds the same as when a script is executed from cron.  When people connect to the server (via ssh or similar) their .bash_profile is executed, setting their environment.  This mechanism does not apply when cron launches a session, so scripts must take care of their own environment.  Sounds like the docker mechanism might be the same, which is what @AlexPoole seems to be getting at.